# Gradle Builds an Empty Jar File

Tags: java, gradle

I converted a project to gradle using `gradle init` from maven after updating the dependencies. `gradle test` works as expected. However, when I run `gradle build`, the jar file that's generated is entirely empty.

I've attempted to tweak the source set to make something happen, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. The directory structure matches what gradle expects from what I can tell everything is nested in `src/main/groovy`

The project's [full code is available on Github](https://github.com/fny/java-factory-bot).

In general what causes no files to be added to a build? Is there additional configuration I need to add besides whatever `gradle init` creates?

Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M3-groovy-3.0'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
}

group = 'nl.topicus.overheid'
version = '0.2.0'
description = 'java-factory-bot'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What going on now is the project is try to build as Java project and get src from src/main/java as it is default from Java project. So, you need `id 'groovy'` not `id 'java'` in `plugins` section to make it look into src/main/groovy and build both .java and .groovy files in there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27137010)

Comment: @PraveenDabral Did I finally answer the question?